# does tcp ESTABLISHED state timeout?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, thrift

[image]

I have served a ThreadPool with 10 threads and on my server I observed long-term held ESTABLISHED connections. These connections block my normal incoming transactions. Is there a timeout mechanism for this? Or how can I actively hangup these connections in application? By the way I am using ThriftRPC with ThreadPoolServer.

Thanks!

Comment: It just means you have open socket connections. Are you making socking calls and you are closing them when you are done? Call `somesocket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)` before closing.

Comment: What do you mean by socking calls? The application I am writing is a server.

Comment: he means socket, as in tcp socket, as in a connection to a port on a server. These are handled generally by the python socket module.

Comment: You showed us a list of TCP connections and you said "server". Presumably you meant a network server with TCP connections. The tread pool itself doesn't create TCP connections so I was trying to figure out what you are doing to make them. As stands, there is not enough information to answer this question. You need to tell us about the network server part of this program.